# Can anyone tell me what Oracle Enterprise Repository is?

Tags: oracle, soa-suite

I'm having trouble translating all the buzzwords on the product page: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/repository/overview/index.html

Is it a document management system? Is it a version control system? etc. I'm not really sure.

I get that it stores the SOA-related things like source code or config files or process definitions or whatnot, but I'm more interested in the physical aspect - how are these fiels/objects stored? Is there a database? Stored in the filesystem? How are they shared, are there access control lists? How do they relate to a deployed application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Oracle have complicated matters a bit by wanting their repository to perform the traditional registry tasks, and thus confusing matters.

Basically, my opinion is that a registry holds metadata and documentation, whereas a repository holds files and deployable artifacts.

I can refer to others thinking likewise, eg. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/woolf/Registry+vs.+Repository and http://best-practice-software-engineering.blogspot.com/2008/04/misc-registry-vs-repository.html

I'm working with the OER (Oracle Enterprise Repository), and frankly, there's a lot of registry, and little repository to that, seen from my point of view.

If I am really positive, then I can fit Oracles use of repository into the SearchSOA description, but I wanted you to be aware of the broad use of the definition of the words, which is almost contradicting Oracles buzzwords (and I hope to have clarified things a bit on the way :-))

Answer (score 1):

I think neither.

http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/SOA-repository

An SOA repository is a database containing the software and metadata that constitute an SOA registry. The registry is an evolving, interactive, controlled-access catalog that facilitates the management of SOA (service-oriented architecture) projects, allowing businesses to easily discover and communicate with each other using Web services.

As a metadata repository, the SOA repository facilitates content validation and workflow support for the SOA. The repository is the medium of record for policies, processes, attributes and schemata related to SOA governance. In some publications and contexts, the repository and the registry are treated as a single entity called the "SOA registry-repository" or "SOA registry/repository."

Comment: I apologize, original question was vague. Edited to have more details of what I'm looking for. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

> "I'm more interested in the physical
>   aspect - how are these fiels/objects
>   stored?"

You're right, it is hard to find the implementation details.  I delved into [the sizing guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/repository/overview/oer11gsizingguidelines-130307.pdf) an it indicates that the Enterprise Repository is a complete application in its own right.  It has an application server and a database.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify - Oracle's SOA governance solution addresses:
1. Service Metadata (from requirements and design thru to asset retirement for WSDLs, XSDs, Endpoints, etc.) for dependency and lifecycle mgmt.
2. Runtime-related metadata (like Endpoints and WSDLs.)
3. Runtime Metrics. (like response time, thruput, and exceptions)

Accordingly. Oracle provides three components that are focused on each of these areas:
1. Oracle Enterprise Repository
2. Oracle Service Registry
3. Oracle Enterprise Manager

finally, just to be clear, source code is stored outside of these components in a traditional SCM.

hth,
Matt